# Random WiFi disconnects or disassociations from Turris Omnia 2020

Tags: wireless-networking, router, openwrt

I have bought a new (wireless) router: Turris Omnia 2020 ([link to the HTML specs](https://www.turris.com/en/omnia/specifications/), also [the whole PDF](https://secure.nic.cz/files/Turris-web/Omnia/Omnia2020_datasheet.pdf)). It is largely based on [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/), it has it as a backend. When connected via RJ45 Cat6 cable - no problem at all, but as there is a limited number of sockets, I have one - my main working laptop connected to it wirelessly to its 5G WiFi. I use both Linux (Mint 20.3) - primary OS, and Windows (10, 21H2). The same thing happens on both systems.

The problem is that after a while (I did not exactly get when and why), say an hour, my Dell Inspiron 15 Gaming 7577 disconnects, or is disassociated...

I am quite near it, so there should be no reason for random disconnects, nor disassociations by the router.

---

### `wavemon` output

```
┌─Interface─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│wlp60s0 (IEEE 802.11), phy 0, reg: CZ (DFS-ETSI), SSID: <CENSORED>                                                 │
├─Levels────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│                                                                                                                   │
│link quality: 86%  (60/70)                                                                                         │
│==================================================================================================                 │
│                                                                                                                   │
│                                                                                                                   │
│signal level: -50 dBm (0.01 uW)                                                                                    │
│===============================================================                                                    │
│                                                                                                                   │
├─Statistics────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│RX: 76,890 (139.28 MiB), drop: 30 (0.0%)                                                                           │
│TX: 45,657 (6.70 MiB), retries: 1,896 (4.2%)                                                                       │
├─Info──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│mode: Managed, connected to: <CENSORED>, time: 2:22h, inactive: 5.9s                                               │
│freq: 5180 MHz, ctr1: 5210 MHz, channel: 36 (width: 80 MHz)                                                        │
│rx rate: 780.0 Mbit/s VHT-MCS 8 80MHz short GI VHT-NSS 2, tx rate: 866.7 Mbit/s VHT-MCS 9 80MHz short GI VHT-NSS 2 │
│beacons: 83,248, avg sig: -46 dBm, interval: 0.1s, DTIM: 2                                                         │
│power mgt: off,  tx-power: 22 dBm (158.49 mW)                                                                      │
│retry: short limit 7,  rts/cts: off,  frag: off                                                                    │
├─Network───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│wlp60s0 (UP RUNNING BROADCAST MULTICAST)                                                                           │
│mac: <CENSORED>, qlen: 1000                                                                                        │
│ip: <CENSORED>                                                                                                     │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no advanced settings of any kind in the simplistic upper interface called *reForis*, you need to enter ***LuCI***:

[image: You need to enter LuCI]

Just enter your login (`root`) and password.

---

Now, I will navigate you:

menu ⟶ Network ⟶ Wireless ⟶ Edit (you will have to edit both 2G and 5G if you use both) ⟶ scroll down to *Interface Configuration* ⟶ Advanced Settings ⟶ finally **uncheck the following**:

*Disassociate On Low Acknowledgement*

> Allow AP mode to disconnect STAs based on low ACK condition

Save and Apply.

---

Ever since I did this, my workstation laptop does hold on WiFi, so I hope it works for you too.